# Have feelings (for/to) (someone / something)

Tags: grammar, prepositions, expressions

I was wondering which preposition is the correct one in the following context:

> - My family and her family show love to themselves but I don’t have feelings ________ her and I try to look for other girls but I haven’t found anyone who can replace her and I want to settle down. We’re 3 years already in this relationship. Please help me.

a. for 
b. to

The writer in the original paragraph used the preposition "for" while it is a little unidiomatic to me. I wonder if "have feelings for someone / something" is a fixed expression.

Comment: No native speaker would ever say “feelings to”. “Feelings for” is the correct phrase.

Comment: Another word choice that you did not offer is “feelings about” which has a different meaning but could be used in the sentence if the relevant message was the intended message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the author.

In this context, I wouldn't use "have feelings to someone" but I would typically use it when specifying a noun phrase such as *"Her feelings of anger **toward/towards** him are inexcusable."* So you *have* feelings *for someone* rather than *to someone.* This preposition here should be avoided.

The author's choice is perfectly idiomatic and acceptable.

It *is considered* a fixed expression.

Comment: Yes, _have feelings for someone_ is a fixed expression meaning _feel romantic love for them_.